# how to avoid changing color of buttons after refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, html

hi i wrote a javascript code to change the button color on click and it works fine (it's first color is white and when i click on it it turns into green) now i have a problem
when i click on the button and the color changes into green if after that i open the same page again or reload it the color turns into white again and i do not want that. any idea thanks

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script>
    var count = 1;
    function setColor(btn, color) {
        var property = document.getElementById(btn);
        if (count == 0) {
            property.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF"
            count = 1;        
        }
        else {
            property.style.backgroundColor = "#7FFF00"
            count = 0;
        }
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>

<input type="button" id="button" value = "button" style= "color:white" onclick="setColor('button', '#101010')";/>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You just intrected with the button means just clicked on that button, it doesn't mean that it's status is saved in the browser. If you want to save that status then you have to add a cookie for the same...

Comment: It's a basic concept of web development...

Answer (score 1):

Try using `localStorage`. Something like this:

```
      var startColor="#FFFFFF";//default color on first visit
      if (localStorage.startColor)startColor=localStorage.startColor;  //if page has been visited before then this color

function setColor(btn, color) {
    var property = document.getElementById(btn);
    if (count == 0) {
        property.style.backgroundColor = startColor;
        count = 1;       
        localStorage.startColor= startColor;
    }
    else {
        property.style.backgroundColor = "#7FFF00";
        localStorage.startColor= "#7FFF00";
        count = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I didnt fiddle with your btn!

Comment: sorry for my last question it was was my fault .
i edit my code but it's color does not change at all when i click

Comment: hey man could u please take a look at your code, my own code was working properly but when i replaced your code instead of my javascript code it does not change the button color on click at all. thank u

Comment: I didn't include the line ` var count = 1;` from your script

Comment: Also this won't work in the Stack Overflow snippet because the localStorage is not accesssible

Answer (score 0):

All javascript objects are flushed once the page changes/reloads/...

You likely want to have a look at cookies (store data at the browser and read it back).

Comment: Yes, or using [Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API). Or storing it server side ...

Comment: If this (or another answer at SO) helped you: please upvote it. You can not upvote a comment but mark it as useful.
If an answer is a solution to your problem mark it as solution.

In the rare circumstance that a comment is your solution ask the commenter to post it as answer, enabling you to accept it.